# System.ArgumentException, when passing parameter using InvokeApiAsync ()

Tags: c#, azure, argumentexception

Attempting to pass some parameters to my custom API running on azure mobile service, using a List reference and Object to sent as parameters.Then I'm facing this Error.

> Could not determine JSON object type for type App7.DataModels.FriendCircle.

```
FriendCircle friendcircle = new FriendCircle();
List<Invitee> inviteelist;
try
{

    Object[] ob = new Object[2] { friendcircle, inviteelist };
    await App.azure_rendezvous_mobile_service_3Client.InvokeApiAsync("saveinvite", new JObject(new JProperty("params", ob)));

} 
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception is :" + ex.Message);

}
```

Comment: Can you attach the JSON string that is being generated from that and the data structure that is expected from your cloud service

Comment: @AydinAdn did not understand what you said

Comment: When you are invoking the API, behind the scenes you are sending a JSON representation of your class to the API, The API is telling you the JSON object doesn't resemble anything it can determine

Comment: @AydinAdn No, it does not happen as such ,all I want is to send a List type reference and an object to the Custom api, Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Mate I can't help you if you ignore what I'm telling you, I can clearly see in your code you converting the object into a JSON object, and you've clearly posted the error that is complaining about a JSON object type.

Comment: @AydinAdn how do I convert my object FriendCircle and List type reference to a JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I tried and was able to send a request to azure custom api.!! 
Serialized my List reference and Object friend circle to Json and hooked it up as Json Properties.

```
var jsoninviteelist= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inviteelist);
var jsonfriendcircle = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(friendcircle);
await App.azure_rendezvous_mobile_service_3Client.InvokeApiAsync("saveinvite",new JObject(new JProperty("jsoninviteelist",jsoninviteelist),new JProperty("jsonfriendcircle", jsonfriendcircle)));
```

P.S Install Package>> Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet manager and use it as reference.